# Resizable UITextView to fit its content

Tags: ios, resize, uitextview

I have done resizing a `UITextView` to fit its content by using the following code snippet ([source](http://www.stuartfarnaby.co.uk/resizing-a-uitextview-to-match-its-content/)).

```
UITextView* textView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,300.0f,10.0f)];
[self.view addSubview:textView];

textView.text = @"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s";

CGRect frame = textView.frame;
frame.size.height = textView.contentSize.height;
textView.frame = frame;
```

My problem is that I don't want to create the `UITextView` programatically. When I add it from the Interface Builder and reference it through a `@property`, the above code doesn't work. The `frame` returns `null`. I've put this code inside `viewDidLoad` so I assume it happens because the `UITextView`'s been initialized or added to the view controller yet(?)

Is there another way to accomplish this without creating the `UITextView` programatically?

Answer (score 0):

You don't do this

```
UITextView* textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,300.0f,10.0f)];
[self.view addSubview:textView];
```

if you have the property hooked up in interface builder. Remove those lines and set it up in IB, and it should work fine.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response. Yes, I did comment out these line and double-checked the connections. No avail though